# "Cannot modify association because the source reflection class is associated via :has_many"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked at other questions with a similar title and issue, but their solutions do not seem to apply to me. Sorry for not being more descriptive, I was already reaching the 150 limit.

---

I have the following Models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tests, through: :weeks

  accepts_nested_attribues_for :weeks, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attribues_for :tests, allow_destroy: true
end

class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :tests, dependent: :destroy
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :week
end
```

And this view:

```
=form_for @event do |e|
  %h3 Event
  =render 'form', e: e # This partial contains the general data of the Event.

  %h3 Weeks

  %table
    %thead
      %th Start
      %th End
      %th X
    %tbody
      =e.fields_for :weeks do |w|
        =render 'week_fields', w: w
  =link_to_add_fields 'Add Week', e, :weeks # Custom helper that adds the fields of the week to the end of the table via JavaScript.

  %h3 Tests

  -@weeks.each do |week|
    %h5=week.start # Prints the 'start' of the Week.
    %table
      %thead
        %th Start
        %th End
        %th X
      %tbody
        = e.fields_for :tests, week.tests do |t|
          =render 'test_fields', t: t, s: week.id
    =link_to_add_fields 'Add Test', e, :tests, parent: week.id
```

This works fine for adding Events and Weeks, but when I try to add a new Test I get an error that says:

*Cannot modify association 'Event#tests' because the source reflection class 'Test' is associated to 'Week' via :has_many.*

I understand this is due to the way I got the associations in the view, but I'm not too sure how I should use them.

This is the code from the `link_to_add_fields` helper I'm using above:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, parent: 0)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder, s: parent)
  end
  link_to(name, '#', class: 'btn btn-default add_fields', id: "add_#{association}", data: {id: id, association: association, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

The helper generates code that's later introduced onto the form via JavaScript. It's a modified version of the one used on a Railcasts episode.

This is what I'm using on my controller to limit the parameters:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :start, :end, :place,
                                 tests_attributes: [:id, :name, :date, :time, :week_id],
                                 weeks_attributes: [:id, :start, :end, :_destroy])
end
```

This works perfectly for editing the data of an already existing Test, but not for new ones generated by the helper. I was reading that (in my case) `tests_attributes` should be within `week_attributes`, since the Test I'm trying to modify *belongs* to Week. like this:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :start, :end, :place,
     weeks_attributes: [:id, :start, :end, :_destroy, test_attributes: [:id, :name, :date, :time, :week_id]])
end
```

I do not know how to make the form to follow this association (or if this is actually a solution). I know that Test cannot be modified cause it's being pulled as read-only, but I'm not sure how to arrange the association within the view, so that it can be saved when I update Event.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got a bit tricky, but I got it. It was a matter of modifying what was *within* what.

I got it working by using something like this:

```
%h3 Tests

-@weeks.each do |week|
  =e.fields_for :weeks, week do |w|
    %h5=week.start # Prints the 'start' of the Week.
    %table
      %thead
        %th Start
        %th End
        %th X
      %tbody
        = w.fields_for :tests, week.tests do |t|
          =render 'test_fields', t: t, s: week.id
    =link_to_add_fields 'Add Test', w, :tests, parent: week.id
```

The trick was to make the fields generated for Test to be within the fields generated for Week. So first I added `e.fields_for :weeks, week do |w|` which would indicate that the following fields *belong* to Weeks, then I limited the data to the current selected Week by using the previous `each` loop.

Next I used the new `w` association in the `fields_for` for Test. This would make every field generated by the render to be in the format of "event[weeks_attributes][*week_id*][tests_attributes][*test_id*]" which is what I was expecting for the parameters in my controller.

The same is done in `link_to_add_fields` where I change the `e` association that belonged to Event, for `w` which belongs to Weeks. This would also change the format of the new records generated via JavaScript, using the format I previously described.

Finally, I had to change the format expected in the controller. I was using the singular form `test`, it had to be changed to plural, as it is possible to add multiple records in the form. So I ended up with something like this:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :start, :end, :place,
     weeks_attributes: [:id, :start, :end, :_destroy, tests_attributes: [:id, :name, :date, :time, :week_id]])
end
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use complex nested form structure here to add test with week. `e.fields_for :tests` should be inside the `e.fields_for :weeks` block for proper associations.

You can get idea from here [Deep Nested Rails 4 Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992959/deep-nested-rails-4-form)