# Cannot modify association ":has_many." using Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with three tables as follows:

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :comentarios, :through => :comments
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  has_many :comentarios 
end
```

and comentario.rb

```
class Comentario < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Everything works fine until I attempt to add a 'comentario' and returns this error

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection in ComentariosController#create 
Cannot modify association 'Article#comentarios' because the source reflection class 'Comentario' is associated to 'Comment' via :has_many.
```

This is the code I use to create a new 'comentario'

comentarios_controller.rb

```
class ComentariosController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @comentario = Comentario.new
  end

  def create
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comentario = @article.comentarios.create(comentario_params)
   redirect_to article_path(@article)
 end

 private
   def comentario_params
     params.require(:comentario).permit(:comentador, :comentario)
   end
end
```

The output returns an error in the line where I create `@comentario` from calling `@article` but I can't see why since Ruby documentation says that once I associate `comentario` to `article` using `:through`, I can simply call something like `@article.comentario`.

Any idea of what is causing this error? 
or do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this association in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The issue is that Rails is confused about which article to use here.

Your `Comment` model `belongs_to :article` but also your `Commentario` `belongs_to :article`... so if you use `@article.commentarios` - it's confused as to whether the article refers to the article of the comment or the article of the commentario.

You will probably need to update your form to be more explicit about what you're referring to. A form for the commentario should actually include fields for the comment it creates.

Somebody else had the same problem here. You may wish to look at the solution here: ["Cannot modify association because the source reflection class is associated via :has_many"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584722/cannot-modify-association-because-the-source-reflection-class-is-associated-via)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, I had to change some variable names because it was not only confusing for rails but also for me. Also the problem you linked here was very resourceful.